# Using @Profile annotation for stubbing external behaviour

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, integration-testing, stubbing

There are several web spring boot java applications. I need to prepare several components for integration testing. My task is to mock all external behaviour such as other projects's components, db calls etc. I found a solution for this using `@Profile`annotation from spring framework. Here's an [example](https://tuhrig.de/a-mocked-spring-security-configuration-for-testing/). I can simply create new profile and declare two beans implementations for each profile: one for real usage, for production and another one for integration testing, for stubbing. It would look like this:

```
@Profile("PROD")
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
}

@Profile("MOCK")
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityMockConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
}
```

But I have doubts about this design. It looks little bit messy for me. Does this solution considered acceptable for task I have?

Comment: Can you define what you mean by "integration testing"? Usually, that includes things like actual real databases, etc., just not the production instances.

Comment: By integration testing I mean that all components (modules if you will) will be tested together for finding bugs and errors in their interaction. One module (microservice) interacts with others and that's have to be tested. So I need to write stubs, mocks for modules so there won't be dependencies of external data sources that can change in time. In that way the data will be the same and test results would be predictable.

Answer (score 0):

Doing this, your mocks and their configuration will be probably packaged with the app running in production.

This seems very odd to me. Would you package your units tests in your deliverd Spring application ? I don't think so. So I would like to say this is a "bad" design since testing dependencies should not be embedded with production code.

However, [Spring's documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html) about `@Profile` annotation is using the exemple of environment segregation.

Now, there is a question which needs to be answered: what do you mean by "integration testing" ?

Is this automated integration test ? Or do you want to run your application in different modes for the testing teams ?

Is this is an automated integration test, then there is no reason to use `@Profile` annotation as automated tests and production code will not be packaged together.

However, if you want your users to make integration tests, then you could create standalone fake project which will be used to simulate the external dependencies you are calling (database, webservices, etc).

Then, `@Profile` can be used to switch from fake to production mode but only through configuration file: fake profile will make call on your fake external services whereas production will call the real external services.

Comment: Integration tests are test that would be executed, let's say, once a day on server in automated way.

Comment: Then as a I mentionned, there is no need to create mock associated to profiles. Instead, use simple mocks (with mockito for instance) on the classes you want to mock.

Comment: That's how I understand the situation. Modules are considered as "black boxes". They would be deployed and launched as simple apps. There is going to be another component, that would contain tests for modules. Modules communicate through the API with each other. These api's bounded to java methods. These methods contain dependencies that I need to stub. So if you create profile for testing you can launch your app with different environment that would be suitable for testing. As far as I know mockito is used for stubbing in Junit testing and that's not the case.

Comment: You can use mockito for any stubbing purposes. That's often used with JUnit but you can use it with jgiven as well for instance.

Comment: I think I found a neat solution that includes using ContextConfiguration, Profile annotations with java based configuration for beans. I'll try it out and let people know how it went.

Comment: It's all about how you end up packaging your application. Any test related code should not be in your prod deployable package.